# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: IDE Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jndi

I have been running a gradle project in eclipse but recently moved to intelij but when I try to run this project in intelij I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial.
```

The Gradle project is compiling fine and I'am able to run it but while debugging it fails at a line where it's running file in eclipse.

Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: it's not likely that this is an "IDE issue", rather an issue of difference in configuration between your Eclipse and IntelliJ

Comment: Ok thanks Stultuske, the issue was not major, the project worked even with this issue after a restart.